# How to integrate yolo-v3 custom object detector in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, yolo

I developed flutter app and `yolov3` custom object detector. Both modules are independent. Now I want to combine those modules into a single project but could not figure out how to use that trained weights of that custom object detector in my flutter app. Could anyone please help me with this integration?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow =) Please add more details of what you want to achieve. Which languages are you using? Which framework? If you make your question more understandable it is easier for us to help you! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether using `Flutter` you're building `android` app or `iOS`.

Anyway to be able to use custom trained `Yolov3` model on your `Flutter` app, follow these two steps.

**1. First you need to convert trained yolov3 model to `tflite` version:**

You can use [this](https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite) repo for that purpose.

Save custom trained Yolov3 `darknet` weights to `tfmodel` that's needed for `tflite` conversion:

```
python save_model.py --weights yolov3.weights --output ./checkpoints/yolov3-416 --input_size 416 --model yolov3 --framework tflite
```

Convert `Yolov3` model to `tflite` version:

```
python convert_tflite.py --weights ./checkpoints/yolov3-416 --output ./checkpoints/yolov3-416.tflite
```

**2. Then you use `Flutter` plugin for accessing `TensorFlow-Lite` API, which works with both `android` and `iOS`** - https://github.com/shaqian/flutter_tflite

a) Create a assets folder and place your label file and model file in
it. In `pubspec.yaml` add:

```
  assets:
   assets/labels.txt
   assets/yolov3-416.tflite
```

b) Import the library:

```
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';
```

c) Load the model and labels:

```
String res = await Tflite.loadModel(
model: "assets/yolov3-416.tflite",
labels: "assets/labels.txt",
numThreads: 1, // defaults to 1
isAsset: true, // defaults to true, set to false to load resources outside assets
useGpuDelegate: false // defaults to false, set to true to use GPU delegate
        );
```

d) To run on image:

```
  var recognitions = await Tflite.detectObjectOnImage(
  path: filepath,       // required
  model: "YOLOv3",      
  imageMean: 0.0,       
  imageStd: 255.0,      
  threshold: 0.3,       // defaults to 0.1
  numResultsPerClass: 2,// defaults to 5
  anchors: anchors,     // defaults to [0.57273,0.677385,1.87446,2.06253,3.33843,5.47434,7.88282,3.52778,9.77052,9.16828]
  blockSize: 32,        // defaults to 32
  numBoxesPerBlock: 5,  // defaults to 5
  asynch: true          // defaults to true
);
```

e) Release resources:

```
await Tflite.close();
```

Comment: the package you are suggesting does not support above yolov2.

Comment: @greenzebra Answer clearly suggests it's applicable for `Yolov3` only and also question was also about `Yolov3`

Comment: Have you used the package you are referring to?

Comment: https://github.com/shaqian/flutter_tflite/issues/206

Comment: I believe this package can be altered to work with YOLOv3.  But I believe you would have to change the image processing.  For reference, alterations to the package to work with YOLOv4: https://github.com/TexMexMax/object_detection_flutter

Comment: @greenzebra Yes I have used it with `Yolov3`. Earlier I misread your reply, I thought it didn't work for you when you used it with `Yolov2` that's why I responded accordingly.

Comment: You are right, If I can recall there was issue in getting `Yolov3` working as architecture was different from `Yolov2`. Eventually I got it working.

Comment: If you're still facing the issue request you to create a separate question with specific issue/error

Comment: Ah I see.  I got that package working with YOLOv4, however now I am using YOLOX with the following: https://pub.dev/packages/ncnn_yolox_flutter

Comment: how do I create my own yolov3 or 4 model for consumption?